# How to build firebase project in circleci including firestore and storage rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, circleci

I have a react project that is hosted in firebase. I am using circleci for builds. This has been working fine. However, I want to include firebase firestore rules and index config and firebase storeage rules in the build.

I have added them to my firebase.json file as follows:

```
 "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
```

If I do a firebase deployment from the command line, the rules and indexes I've configured work fine.

My problem comes when I try and do a build in circleci. I get to the deploying stage and then I get this error:

```
i  deploying firestore, hosting

Error: Error reading rules file firestore.rules
Exited with code 1
```

This is the relevant part of the config.yml:

```
deploy_uat:
    docker:
      - image: google/cloud-sdk
    steps:
      - run: echo $(printenv)

      - type: shell
        name: "Provisioning infrastructure"
        command: |
          curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
          apt-get -qq install -y build-essential nodejs
          echo "node version -> $(node --version)"
          echo "npm version -> $(npm --version)"

          # Firebase tools include native code and need npm 5.x to install into a special dir since it won't have permission to access '/usr/lib/node_modules/'
          mkdir ~/.npm-global
          npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
          export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH

          npm install -g firebase-tools

      - type: shell
        name: "Downloading & configuring archive prior to deployment"
        command: |
          echo ${GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_AMCE_API_ADMIN_CIRCLECI} | base64 --decode > key.json
          gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file key.json
          gcloud config set compute/zone us-central1
          gcloud config set project AMCE-45

          mkdir tmp
          cd tmp
          gsutil cp gs://AMCE-45-AMCE-admin-archive-web/${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}-${CIRCLE_SHA1}.tgz .
          tar xfz ${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}-${CIRCLE_SHA1}.tgz
          ls -al

      - type: shell
        name: "Deploying"
        command: |
          export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH

          ls -al build
          echo "Using env -> $(cat build/env.js)"

          firebase list --token "${FIREBASE_AUTH_TOKEN_AMCE_WEB_CUSTOMER_UAT}"
          firebase deploy -P uat --token "${FIREBASE_AUTH_TOKEN_AMCE_WEB_CUSTOMER_UAT}"
```

Is there some additional dependency that I need to add? I've played around trying to add various firebase dependencies but just generate errors.

Answer (score 1):

After a nights sleep, the solution was obvious...

I hadn't added firestore.rules, storage.rules and firestore.indexes.json to my config.yml file. Once I added them it built fine.

```
      ls -al
      tar -zcvf ${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}-${CIRCLE_SHA1}.tgz .firebaserc firebase.json firestore.rules storage.rules firestore.indexes.json build
```